# Call to undefined function ibase_connect() in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, firebird

I can not connect to a local bank in firebird.

Since I enabled the following extensions in php.ini but not getting any results.

> extension=php_interbase.dll
>
> extension="interbase.so"
>
> extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll

I have also done interbase.so download the file and copy it to the folder:

> /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/

I'm using:

- XAMPP 5.6.8 / PHP 5.6.8 (64bit)
- Linux 14.04 LTS (64bit)

My file database.php

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'SYSDBA',
    'password' => 'masterkey',
    'database' => 'localhost://home//ronald//fire//DEMO.GDB',
    // 'port' => '3050',
    'dbdriver' => 'ibase',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Recalling that the problem is not in my connection string, as I've tried variations like:

- 'database' => 'localhost://home//ronald//fire//DEMO.GDB'
- 'database' => 'localhost:/home/ronald/fire/DEMO.GDB'
- 'database' => '/home/ronald/fire/DEMO.GDB'
- 'database' => '//home//ronald//fire//DEMO.GDB'

Error:
[image]

Thank you for your help!

**EDIT**

By suggesting "@Daniel Waghorn" ran a page with **phpinfo()**

The result can be seen in: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVdzRy?editors=100

I took to perform the following function **get_loaded_extensions(false)**

The function returns me the loaded modules. And as you can see the modules for the Firebird are not loaded.

- Core
- date
- ereg
- libxml
- openssl
- pcre
- sqlite3
- zlib
- bcmath
- bz2
- calendar
- ctype
- curl
- dba
- dom
- hash
- fileinfo
- filter
- ftp
- gd
- gettext
- SPL
- iconv
- session
- intl
- json
- ldap
- mbstring
- mcrypt
- standard
- mysqlnd
- mysqli
- mysql
- PDO
- pdo_mysql
- pdo_pgsql
- pdo_sqlite
- Phar
- posix
- Reflection
- imap
- shmop
- SimpleXML
- soap
- sockets
- exif
- sybase_ct
- sysvsem
- sysvshm
- tokenizer
- wddx
- xml
- xmlreader
- xmlrpc
- xmlwriter
- xsl
- zip
- apache2handler
- pgsql
- mhash

Now how can I load the Firebird modules to run with XAMPP START?

Comment: Is it actually Firebirds database or is it Interbase? Firebird uses "fdb" as file extension... of course extension in itself is not important but it makes me suspect taht you try to use IB's DB with FB or vice versa which wouldn't work.

Comment: I think I understand ... I did not create this bank, just sent me to do some tests, but I believe it is in Firebird it also can use the FlameRobin to open it ... I'm out of ideas. :(

Comment: Create a file with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in it, run it and it'll display information about your PHP configuration. Scroll and see if it lists details for interbase and firebird to check that the modules are actually being loaded by PHP.

Comment: @DanielWaghorn any suggetions? Thanks!

Comment: @ain any suggetions? Thanks!

Comment: @ain The error suggests the library hasn't been loaded into PHP, so this error occurs even before any Firebird or Interbase related connection errors might occur.

Comment: @RonaldAraújo was it listed in PHPinfo?

Comment: @DanielWaghorn see the link (phpinfo) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVdzRy?editors=100

Comment: Please verify that the extensions you require to be enabled are indeed enabled in `/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini` as well as exist at their relevant paths. The reason that I ask is that there are sometimes a few config files in the php directories and the one that gets edited may not be the one in use by PHP.

Answer (score 4):

Just copy fbclient.dll and gds32.dll to apache/bin/ folder and restart apache.

This work for me anfter hours of research.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest everyone to use Easyphp Devserver ([www.easyphp.org](http://www.easyphp.org)) instead of wamp or xampp specially for connecting on Firebird Database (ibase_connect or pdo).